# Java regular expression for double quotes

Tags: java, regex

I have to check the string using Regular expression:

```
String a = "ABC(hello) or DEF("indianbatsmen") or GHK(welcome);
```

Here i will have to check the field DEF has double quotes or not.

I tried with :

`if(!a.contains("DEF(\"w\")")){ }`

It didnt work.

Comment: why do you have to use a regular expression?

Comment: This question is poorly phrased, the title isn't relevant at all. It'll benefit from a downvote from me until this is fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
boolean foundMatch = false;
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\bDEF\\(\"[^\"]+\"\\)\\s+");
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
foundMatch = regexMatcher.find();
```

Not that this **fails** if your string contains escaped quotes.

Comment: Same way i would provide. Because String.contains() has nothing do do with RegEx, it searches for the given charSeq into the String without RegEx compiling.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you were already trying to use regular expression syntax with the `\w` - but you probably want that to be `\w+` (if you require at least one character between the quotes) or `\w*` (if you allow 0 or more characters).  You'll also want to escape the parenthesis using `\(`.

Next, you just need to be using regular expression methods.  `.contains` is just doing a simple String search.  Using the `Pattern` and `Matcher` classes will help here.